# GET function from server replaces HTML-page; very simple client server communication task with express.js and jquery

Tags: html, jquery, node.js, express

I'm really struggling since days and felt weeks with node.js/express.js on server side and html and jquery on client side only to get a simple data exchange  between them. The simple task is:

- client submits  a sentence „Request from client to server“
- server responds on clients website with „Request from client received“

Ok, here is the server side:

```
const url= require('url'),
      express = require('express'),
      app = express();
// Create a server

app.listen(8080, function (){
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
});

app.use (express.static (__dirname +'/public')); // provide public data,here: jQuery

app.get ("/", function (req, res){
    res.sendFile (__dirname +"/ClientServerExchange (1).html");
    console.log (__dirname, +req.url);
});

app.get ("/transmit", function (req, res) {
    res.send ("Request from  client received");
});
```

and here is the client side:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" >
        <title>Client-Server Exchange</title>
        <script src="JS/jquery-3.5.0.js" ></script>
        <style>
            
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready (function (){             
                $.post(location.host, function (){
                    console.log ("Request submitted")});
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Little server exhange</p></br>
        <form action="transmit" method="get">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Request"></br>
            <p id="ServerResponse" name="ServerResponse"></p>
        </form> 
            
        
    </body>
</html>
```

It works, but I don't know where I shall put the sentence „Request from client to server“ as submission data here. Further on, as soon as the submit button is pushed, the website is replaced by a new side showing the server message – means title and button dieappeared, what I don't want. I think I must use AJAX now, and tried to put in something something like this into the  tags like this:

```
$(document).ready (function (){             
    $("input").click (function () {
        $.post(location.host, function (){
            console.log ("Request sent")
        });
    });
});
```

but the html will be replaced as well.
I deleted the action-statement in the form or set it to "/" and set the first parameter of the app.get from "/transmit" to "/" I have the impression that the HTML will be reloaded only, the url appears with "?", but it doesn't do anything else.

I have no ideas anymore. I went through so many tutorials, reference guides and whatever. Either it was to complicated or not well explained for me to filter out what is usable for me.

I.e. JQuery understands GET as receipt of data and POST as submission, while Node.js (Express.js) understands from where to get the data, either from the url via req.query.variable or directly from HTML-tags via req.body.tag ... or something different (honestly said, I didn't understand it ...)

I'm very close to give up my research about communication between server and client.

Comment: Try  `$("input").click (function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
        $.get('/transmit', function (){
            console.log ("Request sent")
        });
    });`
And remove `action` of the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is currently happening on your code is whenever your document is ready a `POST` request is made to your `localhost` which is your `/` route. I can't think on why you have done such code but I can tell this code is wrong in 2 ways. First, you are requesting the homepage 2 times, one when you load the page and the other by the javascript code whenever the document is ready. Secondly, you are making a `POST` request to a `GET` route. The other problem is, whenever you submit the form, the form will redirect you to `/transmit` since it's action parameter is set to `transmit`. Therefore, the why your html code disappears, because your `/transmit` route only sends a sentence `Request from  client received`.

**Here is my solution (with jQuery):**

Change your javascript code to this:

```js
$(document).ready (function (){             
    $("input[type='submit']").click (function () {
        const message = encodeURI($('#message').val());

        $.get(`/transmit?message=${message}`, function (data) {
            $('#ServerResponse').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

And remove the form element.

What to add on the html page:

```html
<input type="text" id="message">
```

**Here is my solution (with vanilla Javascript) [RECOMMENDED]:**

```js
function onSubmit() {
    const message = encodeURI(document.querySelector('#message').value);

    fetch(`/transmit?message=${message}`)
        .then(async res => {
            const {value} = await res.body.getReader().read();
            const text = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(value);
            
            document.querySelector('#ServerResponse').innerHTML = text;
        });
}
```

What to add on the html page:

```html
<input type="text" id="message">
<button onClick="onSubmit()" id="submit-btn">
```

**For both solutions:**

You can access the message on the server code via the `req.query.message`.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts and your solution, Pedro. Your recommendation works well even with JQuery. Problem solved.

Now I understood, how to handle messages and data transmission from client to server and back.

Using back-ticks for template literals was something new for me (for other readers, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).